# getActivity.findViewById() or mView.findViewById()

Tags: android, view, findviewbyid

I would like to know why sometime getActivity.findViewById() works and sometimes it returns null ?

And with myView.findViewById() it works ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: maybe getActivity was null or you missed setContentView before calling the findviewbyId.

Comment: Does the id must be in the layout inflated ?

Comment: of course it should be..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findViewById` is not a global search for a `View`. It only looks in specific places. If no `View` is specified (as in your myView.findViewById() example) `findViewById` will look in the content view for the `Activity` or `Fragment` you are calling it from. Otherwise it will look within the specified view.

You will get null if you are looking for the view in the wrong place - i.e. what you are looking for is not in the place you're searching.

Here's an example: if you're using a `ListView` whose items you are controling with an `Adapter` you would need to call `findViewbById` on the inflated layout for the indivdual items in order to set their child views. Why? Because a `ListView` starts out empty. If you called `findViewById` within the general `ListActivity` you would be looking for list item fields in the wrong place, i.e. the content view for the activity - not the layout that will eventually be inflated for each list item.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing you are in a Fragment and calling getActivity.findViewById().

Looking at the source code, Activity.findViewById() call findViewById() on the Window which calls findViewById() on its decor view.

So when you call getActivity.findViewById() you're searching for a subview of your decor view.

If you call findViewById() directly on a view, you're looking for a subview from the given View.

So if view is not in your decor view subviews, getActivity.findViewById() will return null while view.findViewById() will works.